# How to handle polymorphic queries in GORM

Tags: go, polymorphism, go-gorm, polymorphic-associations

I currently have the following models set up:

```
type TextQuestion struct {
    gorm.Model
    Prompt  *Prompt             `gorm:"polymorphic:Question"`
}

type ChoiceQuestion struct {
    gorm.Model
    Prompt  *Prompt             `gorm:"polymorphic:Question"`
}

type Prompt struct {
    gorm.Model

    QuestionID   int    `gorm:"not null"`
    QuestionType string `gorm:"not null"`
}
```

I would like to get the question associated with a prompt and delete it, but how can that be done? The GORM docs only gives examples for how to create new entries, not querying or other operations.

Of course, I could use a switch statement and handle each `QuestionType` separately, like so:

```
switch prompt.QuestionType {
    case "choice_question":
        // ...
    case "text_question":
        // ...
    }
```

But that would defeat the purpose of polymorphism in the first place.
Is there a more elegant way to handle polymorphic relationships?

Comment: [Delete-with-Select](https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html#Delete-with-Select)

Comment: Hey, that does seem to work for my specific use case, thanks! But what about a more general use case, like say if I wanted to simply retrieve the Question and perform some operations with it?

Comment: Maybe [Preload](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html)